# cordova app blanks out in chrome inspector

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools

Have a most bizarre issue that just started happening two days ago for no reason.   It seems to be getting worse too.  I remote into my home computer routinely to develop my cordova app.  Connected to my computer is a Samsung phone for testing.  After compiling my app to the phone, i launch chrome inspector to see the app and do debugging, UI development, etc

I have been doing this setup for 3 months now and it all works fine.  About two days ago when I compile my app chrome inspector is just showing blank - it says its loaded the project/index.html file - but everything is blank.  No resources, no elements...nothing.  However when I compile and deploy the app to the device, I see the "app name" in Chrome disappear and reappear after that attaches and deploys...I then click the "app name" to open it up in Inspector.  So Chrome see's it deployed, but inspector is just completely blank.

I recompile, redeploy and then it works again.  But more and more lately, even after recompile/redeploy its showing blank again.  I have no idea whats caused this - I didn't do any updates or plugin changes....I was literally testing CSS values when all this started.  And I can't seem to find any references to this issue in google searches.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the "Network" tab in Chrome inspect? Sometimes this reloads all the files sources. Also there could be some ui or load errors that are causing the app to appear blank. Check your console output in the Chrome inspect for any js related errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after some time researching I found that:

**You can't debug the release APK!**

you can just use the `debug` APK

[for more ref](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

Comment: This isn't the release version of my app...its still in development stage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be using a css style on an Ionic Modal or Popover.  Specifically, using `border-radius:1px`.  If defined, the web UI portion of Chrome Inspector would black out.  So to troubleshoot my app development using Chrome Inspector I would have to disable that css style until it was ready to deploy the final app.

However, since then...and within the last 2 weeks or so, it appears that Chrome has fixed this issue.  If you use `border-radius` with an Ionic Modal or Popover, you can see the bottom corners have the radius applied, but the top corners are square.  Seems to me Chrome's fix for the problem was to simply remove top border-radius for rendering in Chrome Inspector.